# Manually execute workbox.expiration.Plugin.deleteCacheAndMetadata() for a route

Tags: workbox

The method `workbox.expiration.Plugin.deleteCacheAndMetadata()` has recently been added to workbox. 
How can I trigger this for a particular route I have setup to cache?

The use case here is that I need to delete a cache when certain actions on the client happen. I could just delete the cache right from the client, but that would leave the metadata (in indexedDB). So I'd rather want to send a message to the service worker and use the workbox method to do the cleanup. 
How can I get a hand of the correct expiration plugin instance to call the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main thing to keep in mind is that the `workbox.expiration.Plugin` instance is not associated with a route—it's passed in to a given strategy. It can live outside of a route definition, and you can reference it later on in your code.

Here's an example:

```
const expirationPlugin = new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
  maxEntries: 20,
}),

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('/images/'),
  workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'image-cache',
    plugins: [
      expirationPlugin,
    ],
  })
);

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data === 'clear-cache') {
    expirationPlugin.deleteCacheAndMetadata();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That wouldn't work using GenerateSW I assume. And out of curiosity, if I were to use the same `expirationPlugin` instance in another route for a cache with another name, it would clear them both?

Comment: If using `GenerateSW` you could put that specific code in a standalone script an import it via `importScripts: ['standalone.js']`. (Or just use `InjectManifest`.) And yes, that will clear both caches if you use the same `expiration.Plugin` in both.

Comment: How to do it without any conditions in expiration - ie without 'maxEntries: 20'?

Comment: If you're not using the cache expiration plugin, then there's no metadata (in IndexedDB) to delete, just the cached responses. You can delete those via caches.delete('my-cache-name'), as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage/delete